# positioning the windows system date time clock window

Tags: c#, winforms

The event method below brings up the windows system date time clock window. My label is on the lower right side of my form and the system date time clock window appears on the upper left side of my form. Is there a way to position this date time clock window to be on the lower right side of my form when this event handler is clicked?

```
    private void LabelDateTime_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // bring up the date & time dialog
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("timedate.cpl");
    }
```

Comment: lookup SetWindowPos

Comment: @namg_engr  You will have a hard time getting that window in this manner. You should run that CP applet through Rundll32.exe, otherwise your process will close immediately.

Comment: @DangerZone  It's somewhat different. Starting a Win32 executable is not the same as starting a Control Panel applet, which is executed by another process which closes after.

Answer (score 0):

Starting a process using `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()` in this manner, is not effective, since the generated Process will exit immediately after the window is created. A .cpl applet is not a standard executable and needs then operating system shell and a launcher to start.

However, a stable process can be created using `Rundll32.exe`, which will generate some threads to host the applet controls and the GDI+ support.
Reaching the applet Window requires some P/Invoke(ing), though, since `rundll` is window-less and it doesn't reference the one it helps create, so the `Process.MainWindowHandle = 0`.

Doc Ref. MSDN [EnumThreadWndProc() Callback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633496(v=vs.85).aspx), [EnumThreadWindows()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633495(VS.85).aspx), [GetWindowRect()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633519(v=vs.85).aspx), [GetWindowText()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520(v=vs.85).aspx), [SetWindowPos()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

ProcessStartInfo psInfo = new ProcessStartInfo() {
    UseShellExecute = true,
    FileName = "rundll32.exe",
    Arguments = "shell32.dll, Control_RunDLL timedate.cpl,,0", //<- 0 = First Tab
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
};

Process sysClockProcess = new Process() {
    SynchronizingObject = this,
    EnableRaisingEvents = true,
    StartInfo = psInfo
};

sysClockProcess.Start();
sysClockProcess.WaitForInputIdle();

//Insert the Window title. It's case SENSITIVE
//Window Title in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\MuiCache\[COD]\[LANG]\
string windowTitle = "Date and Time";
int maxLenght = 256;
SetWindowPosFlags flags = SetWindowPosFlags.NoSize |
                          SetWindowPosFlags.AsyncWindowPos |
                          SetWindowPosFlags.ShowWindow;

//The first thread is the Main thread. All Dialog windows' handles are attached here.
//The second thread is for GDI+ Hook Window. Ignore it.
EnumThreadWindows((uint)sysClockProcess.Threads[0].Id, (hWnd, lParam) =>
{
    StringBuilder lpString = new StringBuilder(maxLenght);
    if (GetWindowText(hWnd, lpString, maxLenght) > 0)
        if (lpString.ToString() == windowTitle)
        {
            GetWindowRect(hWnd, out RECT lpRect);
            Size size = new Size(lpRect.Right - lpRect.Left, lpRect.Bottom - lpRect.Top);
            //Caculate the position of the Clock Windows relative to the ref. Form Size
            SetWindowPos(hWnd, (IntPtr)0, ((this.Width + this.Left) - size.Width),
                                          ((this.Height + this.Top) - size.Height), 0, 0, flags);
            return false;
        }
    //Window not found: return true to continue the enumeration
    return true;
}, ref windowTitle);

sysClockProcess.Exited += (s, ev) => {
    Console.WriteLine($"The process has exited. Code: " +
        $"{sysClockProcess.ExitCode} Time: {sysClockProcess.ExitTime}");
    sysClockProcess.Dispose();
};
```

Win32 declarations:

```
// SetWindowPos() flags
[Flags]
public enum SetWindowPosFlags : uint
{
   NoSize =         0x0001,
   NoActivate =     0x0010,
   ShowWindow =     0x0040,
   DeferErase =     0x2000,
   AsyncWindowPos = 0x4000
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
   public int Left;
   public int Top;
   public int Right;
   public int Bottom;
}

//Callback for `EnumThreadWindows()`.
public delegate bool EnumThreadWndProc([In] IntPtr hWnd, [In] IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool EnumThreadWindows([In] uint dwThreadId, [In] EnumThreadWndProc lpfn, [In] ref string lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, [Out] StringBuilder lpString, [In] int nMaxCount);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, out RECT lpRect);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, SetWindowPosFlags uFlags);
```