# Using Await in BackgroundWorker causes WorkerComplete event to be raised

Tags: vb.net, process, async-await, task, backgroundworker

I have this weird problem.  I need to invoke a process from within a background worker

```
Private Shared _process As Process
Private Shared _StartInfo As ProcessStartInfo
Private WithEvents _bwConvertMedia As New BackgroundWorker
```

Here is the work in DoWorkAsync

```
Private Async Sub _bwConvertMedia_DoWorkAsync(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles _bwConvertMedia.DoWork
  For AI = 1 To 100
    _StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo(".\mycmd.exe", "-1")
    _StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    _StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    _StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    _StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True

    _process = New Process() With {.EnableRaisingEvents = True, .StartInfo = _StartInfo}
    AddHandler _process.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf OutputHandler
    AddHandler _process.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf ErrorHandler
    AddHandler _process.Exited, AddressOf Exited
    Try
      aSuccess = Await AwaitProcess()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    _bwConvertMedia.ReportProgress(ai)
  Next
```

And here the

```
Private Shared Async Function AwaitProcess() As Task(Of Integer)
  _tcs = New TaskCompletionSource(Of Integer)
  _status.Converting = True
  _Error.Clear()
  _process.Start()
  _process.BeginErrorReadLine()
  _process.BeginOutputReadLine()    
  Return Await _tcs.Task
End Function
```

The issue is that when the Await _tcs.Task is executed the _bwConvertMedia RunWorkerCompleted procedure is executed so when I do call the     _bwConvertMedia.ReportProgress(ai)

I get an error that the worker is already finished.

Why is that? can you help me?

What happens is

- DoWork - iteration 1
- at wait process 1
- RunWorkerComplete
- DoWork iteration 2-100

The correct behavior is that the background worker invokes 100 times the process and THEN it finishes the execution and calls the RunWorkerCompleted

Comment: My suggestion is to use `Task.Factory()` if those tasks can be run in parallel, `Task.Run()` if you can manage the eventual concurrency (I don't know what those processes do). When you schedule a task, in any way, you can evaluate it using `ContinueWith()` to test the status and elaborate it if `.Status = TaskStatus.RanToCompletion`.

Comment: The processes are encoding processes so I do not have advantage to have them run in parallel as they use 100% of the GPU/CPU to decode/encode video. If I lunch 2 of them they will simply use 50% each and double the time :). Jimi, thank you for your suggestion, do you have an example?

Comment: This is a special case, since you apparently don't directly manage the process of encoding and is not clear whether this process is concurrently CPU/GPU and IO bound (encodes in memory first, then writes to storage or both at the same time). It looks like you are using a Background Worker just to keep the UI responsive while trying to serialize the process output. But, In this scenario, I think that scheduling a number of parallel processes = to the hardware (CPU) physical threads could be an idea.

Comment: I wrote [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47913838/keep-ui-thread-responsive-when-running-long-task-in-windows-forms/47916647#47916647) a few days ago and something else related to [starting a process and waiting its ending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47836230/positioning-the-windows-system-date-time-clock-window/47843749#47843749). Those two combined already give you an answer. They are, however, written in C#. Take a look and let me know.

Comment: I put together a couple of examples, in case you you still need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some modifications to the code I previously linked and here are two examples of a sequential non-blocking Async/Await procedure and a non-blocking Parallel procedure using `Task.Factory`.

> Since I can't test your program, I simply used `Tracert.exe` to
>   simulate a stdout result to update the User Interface.

To synchronize the running tasks/threads with the UI, I used in the first case the `.SynchronizingObject` of the processes and in the second the TaskScheduler method `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`.

The output from `Tracert.exe` is passed to two TextBoxes.
In the parallel example, I inserted a delay of 1 second between Tasks, to see how the two TextBoxes are updated.

[image]

The Async/Await example can be modified to work differently, since you don't need to wait for a task to complete to start another.

The `ProcessStartInfo` and `Process` objects are added to a *Pool* using a `List(Of ProcessStartInfo)` and a `List(Of Process)`.

> These are used in both examples. Define a correct scope.

```
Public psInfoPool As List(Of ProcessStartInfo)
Public ProcessPool As List(Of Process)
```

**Sequential Async/Await**

> The delegate is used with SynchronizingObject.BeginInvoke if
>   InvokeRequired = true

```
Public Delegate Sub UpdUI(_object As TextBox, _value As String)

Public Sub UpdateUIDelegate(control As TextBox, _input As String)
    control.AppendText(_input)
End Sub

    Dim NumberOfProcesses As Integer
    For x = 0 To 1
        Dim OutCtl As TextBox = If(x = 0, Me.TextBox1, Me.TextBox2)
        Dim _result As Integer = Await Task.Run(Async Function() As Task(Of Integer)
                                     Return Await Test_SequentialAsync("192.168.1.1", OutCtl)
                                 End Function)
        NumberOfProcesses += _result
    Next
```

> The `MediaToConvert` parameter would be the name of the file to
>   convert when you adapt the examples to your needs. The `OutCtl`
>   parameter is just the TextBox used for the output

```
Public Async Function Test_SequentialAsync(ByVal MediaToConvert As String, OutCtl As TextBox) As Task(Of Integer)
    Dim _CurrentProcessInfo As Integer
    Dim _CurrentProcess As Integer

    Dim ExitCode As Integer = Await Task.Run(Function() As Integer

        Dim _processexitcode As Integer

        psInfoPool.Add(New ProcessStartInfo)
        _CurrentProcessInfo = psInfoPool.Count - 1
        psInfoPool(_CurrentProcessInfo).RedirectStandardOutput = True
        psInfoPool(_CurrentProcessInfo).CreateNoWindow = True
        psInfoPool(_CurrentProcessInfo).UseShellExecute = False
        'Name of the executable to start
        psInfoPool(_CurrentProcessInfo).FileName = "Tracert"    'psInfo.FileName = ".\mycmd.exe"""
        'Parameter(s) to pass to the executable
        psInfoPool(_CurrentProcessInfo).Arguments = MediaToConvert
        psInfoPool(_CurrentProcessInfo).WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden

        ProcessPool.Add(New Process)
        _CurrentProcess = ProcessPool.Count - 1

        ProcessPool(_CurrentProcess) = New Process() With {.StartInfo = psInfoPool(_CurrentProcessInfo),
                                                           .EnableRaisingEvents = True,
                                                           .SynchronizingObject = Me}

        ProcessPool(_CurrentProcess).Start()
        ProcessPool(_CurrentProcess).BeginOutputReadLine()
        AddHandler ProcessPool(_CurrentProcess).OutputDataReceived,
            Sub(sender As Object, e As DataReceivedEventArgs)
                    If e.Data IsNot Nothing Then
                        If ProcessPool(_CurrentProcess).SynchronizingObject.InvokeRequired Then
                            ProcessPool(_CurrentProcess).SynchronizingObject.BeginInvoke(
                                                         New UpdUI(AddressOf UpdateUIDelegate),
                                                         New Object() {OutCtl,
                                                         e.Data + Environment.NewLine})
                        Else
                            OutCtl.AppendText(e.Data + Environment.NewLine)
                        End If
                    End If
            End Sub

        'Add an event handler for the Exited event
        AddHandler ProcessPool(_CurrentProcess).Exited,
                Sub(source As Object, ev As EventArgs)
                    _processexitcode = ProcessPool(_CurrentProcess).ExitCode
                    Console.WriteLine("The process has exited. Code: {0}  Time: {1}",
                    _processexitcode,
                    ProcessPool(_CurrentProcess).ExitTime)
                End Sub

        ProcessPool(_CurrentProcess).WaitForExit()
        ProcessPool(_CurrentProcess).Close()
        Return _processexitcode
    End Function)

    Return If(ExitCode = 0, 1, 0)

End Function
```

**Parallel processes using Task.Fatory**

Define a Scheduler and associate it with the current context

```
Public _Scheduler As TaskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
```

> To use `Await Task.Delay(1000)` you must be in an Async method, but
>   it's just for testing the output, it's not needed.

```
For x = 0 To 1
    Dim OutCtl As TextBox = If(x = 0, Me.TextBox1, Me.TextBox2)
    Dim _result As Integer = Test_ParallelTasks("192.168.1.1", OutCtl)
    Await Task.Delay(1000)
    NumberOfProcesses += _result
Next
```

> Note that a new Task is created when the `OutputDataReceived` event
>   handler reports that new data has been received. The UI is updated 
>   accordingly using `DataReceivedEventArgs` e.Data.

```
Private Function Test_ParallelTasks(ByVal MediaToConvert As String, OutCtl As TextBox) As Integer
    Dim _processexitcode As Integer
    Dim _CurrentProcessInfo As Integer
    Dim _CurrentProcess As Integer

    Task.Factory.StartNew(Function()
        psInfoPool.Add(New ProcessStartInfo)
        _CurrentProcessInfo = psInfoPool.Count - 1
        psInfoPool(_CurrentProcessInfo).RedirectStandardOutput = True
        psInfoPool(_CurrentProcessInfo).CreateNoWindow = True
        psInfoPool(_CurrentProcessInfo).UseShellExecute = False
        psInfoPool(_CurrentProcessInfo).FileName = "Tracert"  'psInfo.FileName = ".\mycmd.exe"
        psInfoPool(_CurrentProcessInfo).Arguments = MediaToConvert
        psInfoPool(_CurrentProcessInfo).WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden

        ProcessPool.Add(New Process)
        _CurrentProcess = ProcessPool.Count - 1
        ProcessPool(_CurrentProcess) = New Process() With {.StartInfo = psInfoPool(_CurrentProcessInfo),
                                                           .EnableRaisingEvents = True,
                                                           .SynchronizingObject = Me}

        ProcessPool(_CurrentProcess).Start()
        ProcessPool(_CurrentProcess).BeginOutputReadLine()

        AddHandler ProcessPool(_CurrentProcess).OutputDataReceived,
            Sub(sender As Object, e As DataReceivedEventArgs)
                If e.Data IsNot Nothing Then
                    Try
                        'Update the UI or report progress 
                        Dim UpdateUI As Task = Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub()
                        Try
                            OutCtl.AppendText(e.Data + Environment.NewLine)
                        Catch exp As Exception
                              'An exception may raise if the form is closed
                        End Try

                        End Sub, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness, _Scheduler)
                        UpdateUI.Wait()

                    Catch exp As Exception
                       'Do something here
                    End Try
                End If
            End Sub

        'Add an event handler for the Exited event
        AddHandler ProcessPool(_CurrentProcess).Exited,
                Sub(source As Object, ev As EventArgs)
                    _processexitcode = ProcessPool(_CurrentProcess).ExitCode
                    Console.WriteLine("The process has exited. Code: {0}  Time: {1}",
                    _processexitcode,
                    ProcessPool(_CurrentProcess).ExitTime)
                End Sub

        ProcessPool(_CurrentProcess).WaitForExit()
        ProcessPool(_CurrentProcess).Close()
        Return _processexitcode
    End Function, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, CancellationToken.None)

    Return If(_processexitcode = 0, 1, 0)
End Function
```

Comment: Note that, in the `Test_ParallelTasks()` method I used `CancellationToken.None` as a parameter. You can create a CancellationToken and pass it to the method if you need to Cancel the threads in a safe way.