# Applying a theme from code without theme dialog window?

Tags: vb.net, process, themes

For proprietary reasons – and with the user’s knowledge and consent – my vb.net program (in Visual Studio Community 2017) needs to apply custom themes to the user’s computer at various times.

I can do this in code simply using, for example, myProcess = Process.Start(filename.theme) but this also opens the Windows theme dialog. How can I end the process or otherwise close the dialog window after the theme has been applied?

myProcess.Kill()  doesn’t work because it gives an invalid operation exception error saying that the process has exited, even though the theme dialog is still open.

Alternatively, is there any way to apply a theme directly from code without involving the theme dialog at all?

Comment: The applet process is not actually created by your Process. IIRC, it's `rundll32.exe` that executes `shell32.dll, Control_RunDLL (...)`. Thus, your process will close immediatly after. It's your Process that needs to execute `rundll32.exe` with the correct `Arguments` (the `shell32.dll` instance associated to the applet executable). You need to use `.WaitForInputIdle()` to wait for the applet Window to be available, then `.WaitForExit()` (or, as an alternative, use and wait the `Exited` event e.g. to evaluate a timeout).

Comment: I forgot to mention that a Theme can be applied using the above-mentioned method, adding a command line: `/Action:OpenTheme /file:"[Theme Path+ FileName]"`. And `rundll32.exe themecpl.dll,OpenThemeAction "[Theme Path+ FileName]"` for the more recent versions of the applet.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I'm new to vb.net. Could you give me an example code of the Process statement using rundll32 Control_RunDLL /Action:OpenTheme as you described? I don't know if it's appropriate in this forum but I would be willing to pay for some expert help!

Comment: You know it's not *appropriate*. But it happens that I've already posted [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47836230/positioning-the-windows-system-date-time-clock-window?answertab=active#tab-top) (almost exactly the same). I'ld have marked it as duplicate, but that answer is itself marked as duplicate (wrongly, btw) and it's written in another language (`C#`, but easy enough to translate). And I've updated it yesterday, just in case. If you can come up with something on your own but you have some specific problem, update your question with what you have.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. I'll study your example and see if I can figure it out and translate it to Basic.. In some other forums people accept donations for help with specific coding details. Sorry if that is inappropriate here.